Compositor scale node in 4.2
it seems as if this node has changed functionality between 4.1 and 4.2. For my purposes, I need to take an image and undistort it (lens distortion). This causes the image to run off the bounds of the canvas. In 4.1 I could just use the scale node to essentially "grow the bounds" of the canvas and get the whole image in view. In 4.2 I'm not sure how to achieve this. I can scale and then mix onto a larger image, but I'm still losing the parts of the image that are outside the bounds of the canvas.



